# Apache Camel XPath with nodelist

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

I would like to concatenate all values from the Apache Camel XPath result and add it to the message context. The header should look like: `"|value1|value2|valueN|"`

My route looks like:

```
from("direct:test")
.setHeader("key").xpath("//Identifier", List.class)
.to("mock:result")
```

What is the best way for doing that? Is there a way to implement an own result type?

Comment: You can write a [Processor](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html) to do the transformation yourself.

Comment: I wonder if xquery can do that, as it has stronger transformation capabilities than xpath. Though you can also do it in 2 steps. First xpath to get a list of the nodes, and then another to append the elements with | as separator, for example using a template language or java bean or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

As Willem said, you have to write your own processor.

For such a little thing, my favourite way is to declare a function in the class containing the route definition returning an anonymous Processor like this:

```
private Processor setHeaderWithIdentifiers() {
    return exchange -> {
        List<String> identifiers = new ArrayList<>();
        NodeList nodes = XPathBuilder.xpath("//Identifier").evaluate(exchange,  NodeList.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            identifiers.add(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
        }

        // StringUtils from Apache Commons 3 
        String idAsString = StringUtils.join(identifiers, "|");
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("key", idAsString);
    };
}
```

With that, you do not need to find any complex XPath functions and the code remains clear to understand as long the Processor code remains short.