# Pass and deal xml document with multiple tags in apache camel mybatis

Tags: xml, apache-camel, mybatis

assume that I have document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <main>
   <sub>1</sub>
   <sub>2</sub>
   <sub>3</sub>
   <sub>4</sub>
   <!-- and many, many elements like sub here don't know count of it -->
 </main>
```

How can I deal in my batis with this?

I mean I want to check that my value is equals to any from this xml.

```
select * from table
where value in (and here is this xml document)
```

is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve. First one is using XPATH and get the list of values and pass it on to iBatis call. Second one is try un-marshalling the XML to POJO (using JAXB etc.,) and then extract the values and call iBatis.

[XPath Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529197/apache-camel-xpath-with-nodelist)